# EDID info and HDMI configuration

Tags: c, driver, hdmi, edid

I'm working with the TDA19988 HDMI framer and having troubles understanding how to translate the EDID info to configure the framer output.

For example, from the EDID I can see the following parsed info:
**1280x720 0x41 74.2MHZ

H : 1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 clock 45.0KHZ

V : 720  start  725 end  730 total 750  clock 60.0HZ**

Now, the HDMI framer allows the following to be configured:

 **refpix (preset pixel) = ?

 refline (preset line) = ?

 npix (number of input pixels) = ?

 nline (number of input lines) = ?

 vs_line_start_1 (vertical synchronization line start) = ?

 vs_pix_start_1 (vertical synchronization pixel start) = ?

 vs_line_end_1 (vertical synchronization line end) = ?

 vs_pix_end_1 (vertical synchronization pixel end) = ?

 hs_pix_start (horizontal synchronization pixel number) = ?

 vwin_start_1 (vertical window start) = ?

 vwin_end_1 (vertical window end) = ?

 de_start (data enable start) = ?

 de_end (data enable end) = ?**

I haven't been able to understand how the EDID info is translated to configure the HDMI framer output. Can someone give me some help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about EDID, but since there is no answer yet, I'll explain what I know.

The TV signal comes one pixel at a time from left to right and from top to bottom. The pixel frequency is 74.2MHZ, that is there are 74.2 million pixels in a second.

Each line is composed of 1650 pixels, that makes 74.2M / 1650 = 45K lines in a second. That's the 45.0KHz.

Then, each frame is made of 750 lines. That is 45K / 750 = 60 frames per second. That's the 60.0Hz.

From each line of 1650 pixels, only the first 1280 pixels are used for actual pixels in the image. From pixel 1390 to 1430 there is the horizontal synchronizaton signal. From 1280 to 1390 and from 1430 to 1650 there are unused pixels (HBlank).

And from each frame of 750 lines, only the first 720 are used for actual pixels. From 725 to 730 there is the vertical synchronization signal. Ranges 720-725 and 730-750 are also unused (VBlank).

About your parameters, the `*start*` and `*end*` parameters should be quite obvious. The other ones... well, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for you input! That helps me understand part of the EDID info. Do you understand how the HSYNC, FRONT-PORCH, BACK-PORCH settings are related to all of this??

Comment: @user386093: If I'm not mistaken the HFrontPorch is the time between the end of a line and the begin of the next HSync, while the HBackPorch is the time between the end of a HSync and the begin of the next line. There are vertical *porches, too. The HSync may refer to the length of the HSync pulse. The H values will be measured in "pixels", while the vertical ones are in "lines".